# How to read webassembly

Tags: assembly, webassembly, emscripten

Given the following C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

From a C file, to compile to assembly and open that file to view the assembly I can do:

```
$ gcc hello.c -S -o hello.s
```

And get something like:

```
# mac output
.globl _main
_main:                           
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    ...etc...
```

Is there a similar way to do that with webassembly so instead of getting the binary `.wasm` file I can view the "assembly before assembled" code? Otherwise it gives me:

```
$ emcc hello.c -s WASM=1

# a.out.js
# a.out.wasm // cannot inspect really
```

Comment: Have you looked at [wabt](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `wasm2wat` from [wabt](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt) as suggested by @Margaret Bloom.

The wasm filem generated by `emcc` is a binary wasm file, the format used to efficiently provide `wasm` on the web. `wasm2wat` will just convert this binary form to its human readable textual representation.